# How to link the 2 functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

What do i need to change that `change_sequence_2()` is able to get the info from `tausche_2()`?

```
void tausche_2 (char *c1, char *c2)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *c1;
    *c1 = *c2;
    *c2 = temp;
}

void change_sequence_2(char *F)
{
    int i, j;
    i = 0;
    j = strlen(F) - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        tausche_2 (F, i, j);
        i = i + 1;
        j = j - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: tausche_2 only has two parameters, yet you are calling it with 3, also 'i' and 'j' should be '&i' and '&j'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take the [tour], then read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Since your `tausche_2()` takes its two parameters as pointers and dereferences them, it operates on the values at the adresses you pass to it. Currently you try to pass 3 parameters with only one of them being a pointer. The right way to call it from `change_sequence_2()` would be:

```
tausche_2(&F[i], &F[j]);  // I use the address-of operator to make clear for you,
                          // that this will pass the adresses of the elements at
                          // position `i` and `j`.
```

Alternatively you could add the offsets `i` and `j` to `F`:

```
tausche_2(F + i, F + j);  // to get the same addresses.
```

In `tausche_2()` the passed pointers get dereferenced with `*`:

```
temp = *c1;  // assigns temp the value pointed to by c1
*c1 = *c2;   // assigns the value pointed to by c1 the value pointed to by c2
*c2 = temp;  // assigns the value pointed to by c2 the value of temp
```

so `tausche_2()` when called like above effectively operates on the memory pointed to by the parameter `char *F` of `change_sequence_2()`.